# SQlite request to show people who have birthdays in next 7 days

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to create a Day Message, so when you log in it shows you reminder about who have birthdays in next 7 days.

I this table:
`("CREATE TABLE CLIENTS (USERNAME TEXT NOT NULL, PHONE INT, Date_of_birth DATE, UNIQUE(USERNAME, PHONE))")  ("INSERT INTO CLIENTS VALUES(?, ?, ?)", ('Name', 3435626542, '14/23/2003'))`
So I did try to find any info about those types of requests for SQlite but I was not able to.
Only for MySql and another DBs.

Comment: It's trivial if you use one of the date formats supported by sqlite date and time functions - see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html#time_values

Comment: Sawn, its not that easy, when i'm doing: SELECT username, date(Date_of_birth) FROM CLIENTS its giving me None result. I input data in DB like this: Date_of_birth DATE, and it has / between year,month and day. But when i'm using DATE function its requesting format like this: 2021-07-19  with - sign. So how to handle it?

Comment: Convert your dates to a format that sqlite understands (And that can be meaningfully compared to other dates).

Answer (score 0):

So, Originally I did not put proper Data format from PyQt5 to DB.

It was YYYY/MM/DD
But to be able to use Qdate I need to convert it to YYYY-MM-DD format.
Which I can do with:

```
 self.dateEdit.date().toString('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Now, everything works great.